# Web server not loading pages in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, dns, website, windows-server-2003, iis

I'm using VirtualBox. I had two Windows Server 2003 PCs (SRV1 and SRV2), one for DNS(SRV1) and one as a  webserver (IIS)(SRV2).

I put some HTML page under the default website. But when browsing I'm not getting the exact page.

- I configured DNS correctly – it is resolving the name correctly.
- I changed the network adapter to bridged mode
- I can ping each other with the IP address but can't ping the website (when I ping like `ping www.softech.com`), I'm not getting the webpage (`www.softech.com`)
- I'm not using a public address, just a simple private address.

To be clearer, the webpage resides in SRV1 and there is a DNS entry in my DNS server (SRV1) which points to SRV1. SRV1's(DNS) IP address is `192.168.54.51` and SRV2(webserver) is `192.168.54.52`

Comment: what is the output of the command `ping www.softech.com`, and what is the output of the command `nslookup www.softech.com`? Are you able to access the web page locally from the IIS admin console?

Comment: for nslookup its showing like this name:www.softech.com and address:192.168.54.52  and when trying ping shows like pinging www.softech.com[192.168.54.52] with 32 bytes of data:request timed out showing 3 times

Comment: Please update your question with the *exact* output of the commands `ping www.softech.com` and `ping 192.168.54.52`. Copy/paste the output, don't rephrase it.